# Default master is not applied to SharePoint hosted app

Tags: master-page, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am new in creating SharePoint apps. I have created SharePoint hosted app. It is deployed properly. But default master page is not applied to it. It just showing plain HTML page.
Your help will be appriciable. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't really get the SharePoint master page, but you can inherit the look and feel of SharePoint by using the 'Chrome Control'.

Here's a walkthrough:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179916(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: This seems that given url is for provider hosted app. But I want to do it for sharepoint-hosted app. By default it should be there but I dont know the reason why it is not appearing to my app.

Answer (score 1):

By default your app will use the app.master regardless of what the host is using. Microsoft at this point expects the host is using its default master pages and your app will loom similar with app.master or you can use chrome control to get a similar look but modify as required for the App.  Note this is still independent of the host.  Microsoft has posted some UX guidelines on MSDN for ShatePoint apps.